# Проблема с :link, :visited и "соседскими" селекторами

Tags: html, css, link

Не могу заставить фон элемента стать синим если ссылка :visited. Добавил пример на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1gx37gfL/3/), помогите разобраться

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.articles-item-link:link {
  border-top: 10px solid red
}
.articles-item-link:link + .articles-item-info .articles-item-dateseen .articles-item-dateseen-seen {
  background: red
}
.articles-item-link:visited {
  border-top: 10px solid blue
}
.articles-item-link:visited + .articles-item-info .articles-item-dateseen .articles-item-dateseen-seen {
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="articles-item">
  <a href="#" class="articles-item-link">
    ...
  </a>
  <div class="articles-item-info">
    <div class="articles-item-dateseen">
      <div class="articles-item-dateseen-date">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="articles-item-dateseen-seen">
        Просмотрено
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="<?= $href ?>" class="articles-item-info-caption">
      ...
    </a>
    <div class="articles-item-info-text">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="articles-item">
  <a href="https://jsfiddle.net/" class="articles-item-link">
    ...
  </a>
  <div class="articles-item-info">
    <div class="articles-item-dateseen">
      <div class="articles-item-dateseen-date">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="articles-item-dateseen-seen">
        Просмотрено
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="<?= $href ?>" class="articles-item-info-caption">
      ...
    </a>
    <div class="articles-item-info-text">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1gx37gfL/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В двух словах: так и должно быть.

На [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector) можно найти объяснение такому поведению:

Раньше с помощью этого псевдокласса и, например, метода `getComputedStyle()` сайты могли просмотреть какие сайт посещал пользователь. Для предотвращения этого было решено добавить ограничения на этот псевдокласс, в частности при использовании `+`

> Also, if you use a sibling connector such as `:visited + span`, the `<span>` will be styled as if the link were unvisited.

Т.е. если используется выборка соседнего элемента, то он будет стилизован также как если бы ссылка была не посещена.

И еще статья по теме:
[privacy-related changes coming to CSS :visited](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/)